# Webpack error 'Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String' when trying to compile React server side components using ReactJS.NET and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, webpack-2, reactjs.net

I am getting the following error - 'Module build failed: Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String' when trying to compile JSX components for server-side rendering using Webpack 2 and ReactJS.NET. I have followed the examples as described [here](https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html) as well as in [this example.](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/master/src/React.Sample.Webpack)

My folder structure is similar to the Github example, I have one React component, an index.js file and a server.js file. Here are the contents:

/Content/components/TestComponent.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

class Test extends React.Component {
    getInitialState() {
        return { data: this.props.greeting };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
            </div>);
    }
}

module.exports = Test;
```

/Content/components/index.js

```
module.exports = {
    Test: require('./TestComponent.jsx')
}
```

/Content/server.js

```
var Components = require('expose?Components!./components');
```

And here is my full webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './Content/server',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/resources/dev/scripts/server',
        filename: 'test.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react'],
                }
            }
            {
                test: require.resolve('react'),
                loader: 'expose?React'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    externals: {
        react: 'React'
    }
}
```

I have created an example project [here](https://github.com/martiensk/MVCReact) with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do away with the /Content/server.js file, and instead use the expose-loader in webpack. Here is the updated webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './Content/components/index',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/resources/dev/scripts/server',
        filename: 'test.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('./Content/components/index'),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'Components'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('react'),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'React'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```